# Download My files with REST CALLS CKAN

Tags: api, rest, ckan

I'AM new in CKAN, please tell me if its possible to download my ckan datasets ( my files) using the ckan API.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a call to CKAN's API action 'package_show' to see the details of a dataset, which gives you the 'resources' containing the URLs of the data files. Then you can use these URLs to download the data directly from wherever they are stored.

e.g. doing a package_show from the CKAN API by GETting this URL: https://data.gov.uk/api/3/action/package_show?id=index-of-multiple-deprivation

```
{
"help": "http://data.gov.uk/api/3/action/help_show?name=package_show",
"success": true,
"result": {
  ...
  "resources": [
    ...
    {
      "description": "2010: Sub-domains living environment",
      ...
      "url": "https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/6882/1871676.xls",
    }
    ...
  ]
  }  
}
```

and clearly you can download this spreadsheet from https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/6882/1871676.xls

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is no way to get the file with an http call direclty without passing by the resources package ?
My need is to know ho is possible to call my files with rest endpoint ?
Regards.

Comment: You should edit the question to make that clearer, and it would be good to know why you want to do that.

Comment: Hi i need to get the content of my file in json format with a REST call of the datastroe API.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324712/1308967) shows some Python for downloading via the web UI (using `requests`).